# Reference for the following flow equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

I'm looking for reference on the following partial differential equation. $\partial_tF(t,x) = G(t)((\partial_xF(t,x))^2 + \partial_x^2F(t,x))$, where G(t) is a fixed Schwartz function. If possible, I also want to know if there's reference on the following stochastic partial differential equation, namely the previous deterministic equation with a Brownian white noise $\eta$: $\partial_tF(t,x) = G(t)((\partial_xF(t,x))^2 + \partial_x^2F(t,x)) + \eta$.

I'm a theoretical physicist. So I apologize in advance if the question is trivial for people working in PDE. For me, the origin of these two equations comes from a version of 0-dimensional exact renormalization group flow in the sense of Polchinski, where x in the above equation is to be understood as dynamical fields in usual QFT, t is to be understood as log time scale of renormalization group flow, and F(t,x) is to be understood as a generating functional of all multi-point interaction. For those of you who know RG, all issues related to non-locality, anomalous dimension, etc. are suppressed for the sake of simplicity of toy model.

Also, I think the following comment is important. My approach so far is that this equation has structural similarity with Ricci flow in the sense that the evolution operator contains a square of 1st order derivative (the product of two Christoffel symbols in Ricci curvature) and a 2nd order derivative (the derivative of Christoffel symbol in Ricci curvature). Therefore, I try to massage my equation a bit and see if I can use some technique from Ricci flow to study it, although many of the complexity from Ricci flow is not present here. I'm not an expert so I am not confident that I am on the right path.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Modulo some signs, your first equation is a Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation for a stochastic dynamical system, for a special case. This equation is used for computed an optimal control for a system governed a system of ODEs.

You can consult e.g., these notes (section 2.1) https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~todorov/courses/amath579/Todorov_chapter.pdf 
and references therein.
Also wikipedia has a decent discussion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi%E2%80%93Bellman_equation
See the last example.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. I'm aware that my equation is a HJB equation since this is built from HJB perspective (something called HJB approach to holographic reconstruction in physical language). What I'm not certain is whether there is previous analysis of my particular form of HJB equation. As I understand, HJB equation is a framework where one may fill in different forms of Hamiltonian to drive the flow. So I'm wondering if anything has been said about my form of HJB equation in particular.

Comment: Ok, I guess one can write the optimal control problem from where this comes from, and think about it. Are there any specific properties you want to know about the solution of this equation ? What do we know about G?

Comment: If G(t) is positive, then at least for the deterministic version it can be absorbed on the left hand side by redefining time. The equation then becomes equivalent to the Burgers equation. There are enough papers on the Burgers equation even to satisfy Carl Sagan, so that should give you a start.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: Thanks a lot. That seems exactly what I'm looking for.